# how to fix Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Express Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, backend

> im want to validations email&username and ...
>
> *but in return im have error*

this my code

```
// login
router.post(
  "/login",
  body("username").notEmpty(),
  body("password").isLength({ min: 8 }),
  (req, res) => {
    validations(req, res);
    const {username, password } = req.body;
    const id = users.length;
    
    res.status(200);
    res.json({
      message:'ok',
      data:true
    })
  }
);
```

and this is my function

```
function validations(req, res) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  const errorMessage = {
    data: null,
    message: "validations faild",
    errors: errors.array(),
  };
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
   return res.status(400).json(errorMessage)
  }
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af1LC.png)

Answer (score -1):

"Cannot set headers after they are sent" is caused when your code tries to send more than one response to the same incoming request.

This typically occurs because of errors in the control flow of your code, sometimes faulty asynchronous coding and sometimes just errors in your synchronous control flow that allows more than one `res.send()`, `res.json()`, etc... anything that attempts to send a response.

Now that you're showing the entire code for the http request, we can see that if `validations()` detects an error and sends its 400 response that the main request handler will call validations and will then also send a 200 response.  That's two responses for one request and gives you the error you see.

Remember, you must always send ONE and only ONE response to every incoming http request.

I'd suggest you fix it like this so that `validations()` only returns an error status and your main handler does all the response sending.
It checks to see if an error was returned and if so, it sends an error response and returns to stop further processing:

```
// login
router.post(
    "/login",
    body("username").notEmpty(),
    body("password").isLength({ min: 8 }), (req, res) => {
        const errorMessage = validations(req);
        if (errorMessage) {
            res.status(400).json(errorMessage);
            return;
        }
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        const id = users.length;

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'ok',
            data: true
        });
    }
);


function validations(req) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        const errorMessage = {
            data: null,
            message: "validations failed",
            errors: errors.array(),
        };
        return errorMessage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks please check my new code

Comment: @pouya - Code suggestion added.

Comment: thanks but you can make function with async and retrun res.status & json in function

Comment: @pouya - There are thousands of ways to code it.  The point is that if you're sometimes going to send an http response in that function you HAVE to communicate back from the function whether you sent a response or not so that caller knows so it won't also send a response (thus creating two attempts for the same request at sending a response).  There is NO reason at all for the code you show in `validations()` to be `async` as it does not use promises in any way.

Comment: @pouya - I've described the problem in your code, both generically and specifically, and shown you a solution.  Not sure what else I can do.  Take what you've learned here and code it however you want it to be structured.